# adding android chip from array

Tags: android, android-chips

i have an array like this:

```
['A','B','C']
```

and i want to display it in tags/chips in my android i am really new to this concept and not sure of  what chip library to use for this i just want to get it from an array and display something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
 {
     //dynamically add chips from the array
 }
```

if possible direct me towards a tutorial for this.

so my final result should be somthing like :

[image]

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/hootsuite/nachos

Comment: or this can also help you https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#

Comment: thank you the nachos Library did the trick

Answer (score -2):

Here I am creating a ArrayList of string for Chip header

```
String []myList = {"Chip1", "Chip2", "Chip3", "Chip4"};
```

Now I will render through each ArrayList element

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    // Here I am creating Chip view dynamically using current Context
    Chip chip = new Chip(binding.chipGroup.getContext()); 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);

    chip.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    chip.setText(myList[i]);
    chip.setCloseIconEnabled(true);
    chip.setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorChipIconTint));
    chip.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorChipText));
    chip.setCloseIconTint(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorChipCloseIcon));

    chip.setClickable(true);
    chip.setCheckable(false);

    binding.chipGroup.addView(chip);
    }
```

Comment: please try to be more descriptive in your explanation